# "halfthink sets" contain n and n+1

Tags: combinatorial-proofs, combinatorial-number-theory

A problem: Georgina calls a 992-element subset $A$ of the set $S = \{1, 2, 3, . . . , 1984\}$ a halfthink set if

• the sum of the elements in $A$ is equal to half of the sum of the elements in $S$, and

• exactly one pair of elements in $A$ differs by 1.

She notices that for some values of $n$(less than 1984), there are no halfthink sets containing both $n$ and $n+1$. Find the all possible values of $n$.

I call the values $n$ is halfthink if there are a halfthink set containing both $n$ and $n+1$ and I have tried this problem for easy cases:

Case I: $S=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$. We need find four numbers that the sum of them is 18. Notice that all even numbers, 2,4 and,6 are halfthink. 4 is obviously halfthink since we have 2+4+5+7=18; 2 is halfthink since we have 2+3+5+8=18; symmetrically, we can get 7+6+4+1=18, so 6 is halfthink. We can claim that if $n$ is halfthink, then so is $8+1-n$ and vice versa. Then all odd numbers are not half think. For example, if we choose 1 and 2, then we need to find two numbers left that the sum of them is 15(=18-3), however the only possible pair is 7 and 8. Similarly we can know that 3 is not halfthink, so symmetrically we can get 5 and 7 is not halfthink.

Case II: $S=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12\}$. We need find six numbers that the sum of them is 39. Similarly all even numbers are halfthink, since
2+3+5+7+10+12=39, 1+4+5+7+10+12=39, 2+4+6+7+9+11=39, and the symmetrical property. For odd numbers, 3, 5, 7 and 9 are still not halfthink, however 1 and 11 is halfthink for 1+2+6+8+10+12=39.

...

So I guess that for $S=\{1,2,...,4m\}$, all even numbers, 2,4,..., and $4m-2$, are halfthink; only $2m-3, 2m-1, 2m+3, 2m+5$ are not halfthink and the odd numbers left are halfthink.

Is that true? How to prove that?

Comment: Great work with the small cases. How can you generalize that to support your hypothesis? Maybe think about how we can move from one half think set to another.

Comment: @Calvin Lin Thank you for the comment! In fact my generalization is so arbitrary that I call it "guess" since I only considered the case $m=2$ and case $m=3$. So far I have only known that if $A=\{a_1, a_2, ..., a_{2m}\}$ is halfthink for $S=\{1,2,...,4m\}$, then so as $B=\{4m+1-a_1,4m+1-a_2, ..., 4m+1-a_{2m}\}$, which I called symmetrical property above. Can you explain "move from one half think set to another" in detail? Are there other ways to "move"? Glad to your comment again!